# Query String, Can I show single item from a list using a query string?

Tags: list, list-view, filter, item, query-string

Used this to pass a value to a form, but can I use a query string for a single list item ID, provide to users and have that filter a list for me? Or do I need some CQWP that takes a parameter from a query string?

If so does anyone have a good example or resource for this please?

Thanks; appreciate as always!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes very easy even, via SharePoint Designer:

1. Go into your page use the Insert menu, choose Empty data View.
2. Click the in page on the "Choose data Source Details" and choose your target list.
3. From the Data Source windows choose fields to show and via the button "Insert Multiple Item View". Then choose from the Design your required. Now you should have all items.
4. With you web part  selected, use the Filter button and in the window choose the column to filter after, e.g by ID. Make a condition as such "ID Equals" and use the ADD NEW PARAMETER. In the window to define the parameter you have multiple types, and you need to use QueryString. In the 2nd text box from the 3 available type the name of the Variable as you send it into your QueryString.
5. Just to be sure, via PAGING (in case you do not use a field with unique values, such as ID), make sure you Chose to show a single item

That's it! ALso have a look at this article for more details http://madanbhintade.wordpress.com/2012/01/08/sharepoint2010dataviewwebpart/

Comment: Is there any any way to do this with listform or custom list form that creates the form for you.  filter is not avaiable, and changing parameters does not see to work.

Comment: you could pass in the ID and then simply Filter the Web Part on that- is a matter of 30"